# Grid method isn't working for a clock in python

Tags: python, tkinter, methods, grid

I've tried various sources, googling, etc, but I'm unable to tell why can't I use grid to put this clock in the **bottom-right corner**. I've tried using gird_columnconfigure, sticky, etc.

```
from tkinter import *
import time


def tick():
    time_string = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    clock.config(text=time_string)
    clock.after(200, tick)


root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x450')
clock = Label(root, font=("times", 25, "bold"), bg="white")
clock.grid(row=2, column=4)
tick()

mainloop()
```

Comment: `import *` is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: Okay, but that didn't cause the problem right? I am new to Python.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be at fault here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, you can add:

```
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

But since there is only one widget in your case, the above suggestion may not work if you add more widgets to the window.